# How to create visual DB model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC4.0. I have a requirement details below mentioned.

Create Model using Telerik grid

Can somebody suggest any useful link for the same?

Comment: You're looking for a `Code First` approach. Create your models with their mapping and flush it trough `Entity Framework`. http://codefirst.codeplex.com/

Comment: @JeroenVannevel +1. Thanks for the help. Can you please confirm if the point 3 and update DB from model. also suits the same link. I meant, using Model, can we update Database also ?

Comment: Yes, just use the `Migrations` tool. Add classes, execute Migrations and your database is updated. You can find an entire example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [Model First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj205424) approach in EF.

Apart from EF there are also some third party software that addresses this problem. For example [CodeFluent Entities](http://www.softfluent.com/products/codefluent-entities/features).